# Kivy Button not displaying

Tags: python, kivy

According to this code which I have seen in a youtube video there is two side by side Button shown in kivy screen but in my case there is blank screen. no button display.
for helping thanks in advance .
I am new in Python and kivy.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b1 = Button(text="Button A")
        b2 = Button(text="Button B")
        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(b2)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work ;) The issue is that you just typed 'pass' in your TheLabApp-class. When you work with a .kv file, this could work but you aren't from what I am seeing.

```
class TheLabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BoxLayoutExample()
```

You should take a look at the documentation (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html) to understand why your code isn't working. They give good examples.

**Edit:**

When you work with the .kv file you should work like this:
First of, name your .kv file as your Application-name (TheLabApp.kv)

**.kv**

```
BoxLayoutExample:

<TheLabApp>:
    BoxLayoutExample:
```

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b1 = Button(text="Button A")
        b2 = Button(text="Button B")
        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(b2)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```